# set onCliccklistener to notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have an application that shows a play pause notification.I want to when a user tap on the notification a service in the app be called and I do my stuff in that service.

I have done it for my notification item widgets like buttons but now I want to handle user tap on whole of notification bar.any help?

This is my code for handling on items click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context , MyNotificationService.class);
intent.putExtra("ID","play");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,0,intent,0);
myRemoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.myButton);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(YourActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

There you go :) This will open 'YourActivity' when the notification is tapped.

Comment: tnk you for your answer but I want to call a service instead of run new activity.what should I do?

Comment: do you know how can I put onCancle method for my notiication?